Guy acquires crazy demonic hand that kills and does bad things to people
A movie where a guy acquires a crazy demonic hand that kills and does bad things to people and it's like a cursed hand which he tried to kill several times, it killed his 2 friends and respawned them as zombie-like people. I've watched it a long time ago, possibly a 90s film.
I also remember that he tried to cut it and it escaped to spread evil or something... another thing that I remember is that the leading lady is very hot which gives me a ...you know.

Though I first thought of Evil Dead II, this sounds more like Idle Hands from 1999 with Seth Green, Jessica Alba and Vivica A. Fox:

Anton would like very much to go about his daily routine of smoking weed, watching TV, and lusting after the girl across the street. The only thing stopping him is his demon-possessed right hand which seems determined to kill anyone it encounters. After dropping his parents and his best friends, the hand sets its sights on Molly, the punk rock girl of Anton's affection. Luckily for him, Pnub and Mick (his recently deceased buds) are back from below ground to help the problem get solved. Only they better get cracking because the hand is out for more than just a killing spree.

He chops it off at some point but is unable to control it. Here's the trailer:



